# ¿Cómo quitar el signo $ y puntos a un número en formato de dinero en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, formato

Tengo un número en formato de dinero que luce de la siguiente forma: `$ 178.000` (el número lo obtengo de una *API*), y quiero convertirlo a un número corriente, así: `178000`.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo con *JavaScript*?

Agrego la expresión regular que he intentando construir:

```
const monto='$ 178.000'
const montoFormat= monto.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"")
```

Comment: Te sugiero que agregues el código de lo que haz intentado hasta el momento.

Comment: usa la funcion ```replace```, [mira](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

Comment: @GFlores98 hecho

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Si quieres solo eliminar el signo `$` y el punto `.`, haz solo una consulta de regex para esos dos caracteres especiales

```js
var monto = "$ 178.000";
var montoFormat = monto.replace(/[$.]/g,'');
console.log(montoFormat);
```

Comment: Funciona, muchas gracias!. Cómo sería para agregar a esa misma consulta regex también la ","? en algunas regiones se usa la ,

Comment: Sólo agrega entre los corchetes [] la ",". Si quieres aprender más de expresiones regulares puedes http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/utiles/regex.php ver aquí

Answer (score 2):

Si el número viene con la cantidad de centavos, hay que mantener solo los números y la coma.

Ejemplo, `$ 2.178.000,58'`, que pasado a palabras el significado es el siguiente:

> Dos millones, ciento setenta y ocho mil pesos **con cincuenta y ocho centavos.**

Se puede quitar una exclusión, lo cual hace que se mantenga. Se excluye con el signo de elevado `^`. Lo que se excluye son números `\d` y las comas `,`.

Entonces hay que reemplazar la exclusión `[^\d,]` por un string vacío `""`. Esto hace que se quite todo lo que no sea ni número ni una coma, y de esta manera se mantienen los números y la coma.

Opcionalmente, luego se puede reemplazar la coma por un punto para el formato americano:

```
.replace(",",".")
```

Código:

```js
var monto = '$ 2.178.000,58'
var montoFormat = monto.replace(/[^\d,]/g,"")

  .replace(",",".") // Opcional

console.log(montoFormat)
```